# what if geometric sequence + geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, algorithms, relations, quadratics

I wrote a program that basicly can find the formula of the sequence that created with any-degree equation. 
For example if you give my program that sequence:
[1926, 2811, 833240, 28778265, 398155842, 3267499271, 18997669476, 86360995365, 326275263710, 1066959810387, 3107266779216, 8227981408241, 20122182489690, 45999898361055]
My program is going to return you a equation immediately.

There is no problem that kind of sequences:
13*x^11 + -22*x^10 + -15*x^9 + 20*x^8 + -5*x^7 + 13*x^6 + -33*x^5 + 11*x^4 + -6*x^3 + 54*x^2 + -101*x + 1997

I want to do same thing in geometric sequences but fail.
For example:

I have a simple geometric sequence like that: (2^x)
[2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
And another one: (3^x)
[3, 9, 27, 81, 243, 729, 2187, 6561, 19683]

I can find nth term of these simple sequences and i can create rest of sequence.
I know there is a formula : a*d^n-1

There is no problem until now. But what if add these number and i create a new sequence.

For example: (3^x + 2^x + 1)

[6, 14, 36, 98, 276, 794, 2316, 6818, 20196]

I can't get any relationship.

My question : "Is there a relationship between these numbers?"
If there is, how can i find it?
Unless, why?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already said: you have a program to find the rule to a sequence. If I give you two numbers, there is a unique linear sequence with those two numbers as the first two terms. Say $a_1=5$ and $a_2 = 7$ then the linear sequence with $a_n = 2n+5$ has $a_1 = 5$ and $a_2 = 7$. But what about the quadratic sequence with $a_n = kn^2 + (2-3k)n + (2k+3)$? This sequence has $a_1 = 5$ and $a_2 = 7$ for all possible choices of $k$. There is an infinite, uncountable number of quadratic sequences with $a_1 = 5$ and $a_2 = 7$. I could find an order ten sequence which has the same first nine terms of $3^n+2^n+1$. There is an infinite, uncountable number of order 11 sequence which have the same first nine terms of $3^n+2^n+1$.

Comment: A better answer...http://www.mymathforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=40160

Comment: @frukoprof Ask a stupid question, get a stupid answer.

Comment: alright, man. Everyone is stupid and you are a genuis. Congratulations...

Comment: @frukoprof Thanks :o)